# Is there a better alternative to extract nested value from Json Object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I extract generically val2 like below, it works, but is there a lighter way ?

```
let myJsonObject = {
    'key1': {'key1.1': 'value1.1'},
}
let val1 = myJsonObject['key1'];
let key = Object.keys(val1)[0];
let val2 = val1[key];
```

Comment: myJsonObject.key1['key1.1'] should work the same .

Comment: How about specifying the `nested path` in `string format` then `splitting it` and after that making use of `reduce` to get the value, if your object is deeply nested.

Comment: `Object.values(myJsonObject['key1'])[0]`?  It's not really clear what you mean by lighter and what you're trying to do.  Do you want a path selector like lodash's `_.get` function or do you just want to be able to iterate on the values of an object?  You need a better (reasonably complex) example of the kind of operation that you are trying to do that gets overly verbose that you want simplified.

Comment: For ex: `demo = {key:{val:{json:'true'}}}`, and you have a path such as `path ='key.val.json' ` and then reducing it by passing the Object. Like this way : `path.split('.').reduce((acc, elem)=>elem && acc[elem], demo)`

Answer (score 0):

`myJsonObject['key1']['key1.1']` gives you the same result, but this by itself doesn't go anywhere.

It would be a lot more interesting and useful for you if you could explain the bigger picture of why you need to read a nested field in your object so that we can discuss about a more general and meaningful solution.

Some info could be where this object comes from and what possible values/formats it can get.